# Easy way to find and replace strings in grails?

Tags: string, grails

There are about 200 .gsp grail files.

I have a .properties file containing about 200 static texts that need to be ipdated

Each static text may need to be replaced more than one time, and in more than one file.

Is there an easier way than to manually find/replace ever instance of static text?

I was thinking of writing a java program to do this.. but it seems parsing and indexing strings may take a while or cause issues.

Comment: try Replace Structurally from IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what am looking for!

Comment: it seems I cant find structurally for .gsp files

Comment: I bet `html` will work for you

Comment: Its still unable to find any instances. Ive tried all the scopes, such as project files, projects and libraries, etc

Comment: hm, maybe I'm wrong. Actually I've never used for GSP, only for Java code. was sure that it does work for any file

Comment: It seems that it can only find the complete line. i.e if I search for <span>Select your Series</span>, it will find it. If I search Series< or anything less than the whole line, there will be no results. Is there a setting around this? I just found there is a complete match variable, im trying to disable this

Comment: If you are on a Unix like system you could do something like : find . -name "*.gsp"|xargs perl -ne 's/Link/LINK/g and print'... just write a bash loop around your properties file and make the necessary changes...